# wxpython add line to TextCtrl

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have a multi line, read only TextCtrl in wxpython
I know how to set values using

```
myTextCtrl.SetValue('hello')
```

But this will change whatever I previously had in my TextCtrl...
How do I add a new line and keep whatever I had before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either `widget.AppendText` or `widget.WriteText` will write a new line each time if you send your string with a newline character (like 'hello\n')

`AppendText`, would append the text at the end of the text in the control. `WriteText` is the same except because the new text in placed at the current insertion point.

Answer (score 2):

I've had issues like this before and want to share what I discovered on this topic for future inquiries.

In order to successfully have a multiline `widget.TextCtrl` object that interprets newline (\n) characters properly, two conditions have to be met:

1) The `wx.TE_MULTILINE` tag is included in the "style" argument when instantiating the object.

2) When setting the text value of the `widget.TextCtrl` object, you must use `widget.SetValue` and not `widget.SetLabel` to properly include the newline character. Using `widget.SetLabel` removes the newline characters entirely, and possibly other non-printable characters as well.

Comment: the `wx.TE_MULTILINE` is a good addition to Joaquin answer, but `widget.SetValue` doesn't work. `widget.WriteText` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
myTextCtrl.AppendText('hello')
```

This does not add a newline character on its own, so you will have to include that in the string if needed.